# AMDGPU installation fails due to dependency problems on POP OS 20.0.4

Tags: linux, drivers, dpkg, amd-graphics, pop-os

I've been attempting to install the amdgpu drivers for pop os 20.04
However it keeps failing due to "dependency problems".

Kernel version is 5.4.0-7642

This is the output below. The entire output can be found at https://hastebin.com/umudecefit.log
Hopefully someone can provide some insight into this issue.
Many thanks.

```
    DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 5.8.0-7630-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.0-7630-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-7630-generic (amd64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of am
dgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.14.224-1147286); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu (1:19.1.0-1147286) ...
Setting up mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Setting up amdgpu-pro-core (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up opencl-amdgpu-pro-comgr (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Setting up opencl-orca-amdgpu-pro-icd:amd64 (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Setting up vulkan-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.40-1147286) ...
update-alternatives: using /opt/amdgpu-pro/etc/vulkan/icd.d/amd_icd64.json to provide /etc/vulkan/icd.d/amd_icd64.json (amd_icd64.json) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /etc/vulkan/icd.d/amd_icd64.json with a link
Setting up libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Setting up libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro:
 amdgpu-pro depends on amdgpu (= 20.40-1147286); however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Setting up opencl-amdgpu-pro-icd (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up ocl-icd-libopencl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up clinfo-amdgpu-pro (20.40-1147286) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro-lib32:
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu (= 20.40-1147286) | amdgpu-hwe (= 20.40-1147286); however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.
  Package amdgpu-hwe is not installed.
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu-pro (= 20.40-1147286) | amdgpu-pro-hwe (= 20.40-1147286); however:
  Package amdgpu-pro is not configured yet.
  Package amdgpu-pro-hwe is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro-lib32 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libglapi1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.40-1147286) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up libglapi1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:amd64 (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:i386 (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-pro-appprofiles (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-pro:i386 (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:amd64 (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:i386 (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext:amd64 (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up amdgpu-lib (20.40-1147286) ...
Setting up amdgpu-lib32 (20.40-1147286) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
 amdgpu-pro
 amdgpu-pro-lib32
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: In the beginning of your question, you state that the "Kernel version is 5.4.0-7642". But in the command output, it's failing on kernel 5.8.0-7630.

Answer (score 1):

You have some incompatible Linux kernel headers installed.
At least version 5.8.0-7630 has to be removed.
The amdgpu-pro drivers are meant to be used with Linux v5.4.